# Heroku memory issues using puma

Tags: memory, heroku, puma

[image: memory usage]

I have checked my logs and ever since starting using puma (Switched from unicorn which didn't have this issue) as my web server on heroku I have what appears to be a memory leak problem.

The server itself is idle and the logs show no requests, yet my memory utilization on web dynos keeps rising to the limit and then overquota. Any ideas or suggestions on how to look into this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to go to a dyno type (Performance Large) with more RAM to accommodate the memory caching that Ruby/Rails was doing. I couldn't find a way to stop it from peaking around 2.5GB, but it did indeed level off after that.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot provide an answer, but I am researching the same issue. So far, the two following links have proved most educational to me:
https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/342. A possible work-around (though supposedly not vetted for Heroku production) is to use the puma-worker-killer gem: https://github.com/schneems/puma_worker_killer. Hope this helps.

Comment: do you have a link for where it states that puma_worker_killer is not vetted for Heroku production? Thanks.

Comment: They do recommend it as a stopgap solution, however, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-memory-use#too-many-workers-over-time

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this and in the fall of 2019 Heroku added a Config Var to new apps, but it has to be manually added to apps created before then.

MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2

They have a write up about it here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1683

You can also try out using Jemalloc https://www.speedshop.co/2017/12/04/malloc-doubles-ruby-memory.html